# redshift delete records with timestamp of saturday

Tags: amazon-redshift

Hi Guys I'm new to the redshift and need help on this please
The requirement is to delete records from a table using the dw_created_date where the weekday is saturday.
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Amazon Redshift yet but after reading the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html) you should find your records using:

```
SELECT *, to_char(dw_created_date, 'D') dayofweek FROM table
```

Number 6 in "dayofweek" would refer to a saturday so this would delete the records:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE to_char(dw_created_date, 'D') = 6
```

Good luck!

Comment: Great to hear! And I can recommend reading a bit more in the docs, there will be some more interesting topics to read about, too!

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Redshift function [TO_CHAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html) allows you to extract date parts and information about dates and timestamps from Redshift and to obtain date parts.

You can find information about the [TO_CHAR function here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html).

In order to extract the information that you need from the TO_CHAR function, you need to use the appropriate datetime format string. As examples, "D" returns the day of the week number, DY returns an abbreviation of the weekday name, and DAY provides the complete fully spelled weekday name.

You can find the information about the [date time format strings for Redshift here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html).

Below I am providing a quick snippet of code that shows how the TO_CHAR function works.

```
create table tba (colint integer, colts timestamp) distkey (colint) sortkey (colts);
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (1, '2016-08-08 08:08:08');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (1, '2016-08-09 09:09:09');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (1, '2016-08-10 10:10:10');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (1, '2016-08-11 10:11:11');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (12, '2016-08-12 12:12:12');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (13, '2016-08-13 13:13:13');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (14, '2016-08-14 14:14:14');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (15, '2016-08-15 15:15:15');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (16, '2016-08-16 16:16:16');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (17, '2016-08-17 17:17:17');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (18, '2016-08-18 18:18:18');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (20, '2016-08-20 20:20:20');
insert into tba (colint, colts) values (6, '2016-08-06 06:06:06');
select *
, to_char(colts,'D') day_of_week_number 
, to_char(colts,'DAY') day_of_week_name 
, to_char(colts,'DY') day_of_week_abbrev
from tba;

 colint |        colts        | day_of_week_number | day_of_week_name | day_of_week_abbrev 
--------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------
     15 | 2016-08-15 15:15:15 | 2                  | MONDAY           | MON
     16 | 2016-08-16 16:16:16 | 3                  | TUESDAY          | TUE
     18 | 2016-08-18 18:18:18 | 5                  | THURSDAY         | THU
      1 | 2016-08-08 08:08:08 | 2                  | MONDAY           | MON
      1 | 2016-08-09 09:09:09 | 3                  | TUESDAY          | TUE
      1 | 2016-08-10 10:10:10 | 4                  | WEDNESDAY        | WED
      1 | 2016-08-11 10:11:11 | 5                  | THURSDAY         | THU
     12 | 2016-08-12 12:12:12 | 6                  | FRIDAY           | FRI
     13 | 2016-08-13 13:13:13 | 7                  | SATURDAY         | SAT
     14 | 2016-08-14 14:14:14 | 1                  | SUNDAY           | SUN
     17 | 2016-08-17 17:17:17 | 4                  | WEDNESDAY        | WED
     20 | 2016-08-20 20:20:20 | 7                  | SATURDAY         | SAT
      6 | 2016-08-06 06:06:06 | 7                  | SATURDAY         | SAT
(13 rows)
```

Last, but not least, there are two very important things that you should pay attention if you are new to Redshift. Every time you delete or update a significant amount of data, there are 2 things you should always do:

1. [VACUUM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html) - Amazon Redshift does "logical" deletes of data when a "DELETE" or "UPDATE" data. So if you change a substantial number of records, you should run a [vacuum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html) to physically remove the data from your table. My "rule of thumb" is that whenever more than 5% of the data has been deleted or updated, it is time to run a [VACUUM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html). You should run a command such as `vacuum full tab;`. [You can find more info about VACUUM here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html)
2. [ANALYZE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE.html)- Amazon Redshift depends on accurate statistics on table data and distributions in order to create the most efficient query plan. If you delete, insert, or change a "significant" portion of data. You should run an [ANALYZE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE.html) command on the table to make sure the database has up-to-date statistics. A sample command is `ANALYZE VERBOSE TBA;` . [You can find more information about ANALYZE here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE.html)